# Maven - rename files with names put in variable

Tags: maven, properties, file-rename, maven-antrun-plugin

so here is my problem,
I have files, each of them must be renamed differently when using different profiles.

So I have 2 .properties files, dev.properties and rec.properties
in dev.properties you can find :

```
machineName=marin
prefix=DEV
fileOneName=node
```

in rec.properties you can find :

```
machineName=marin
prefix=REC
fileOneName=node
```

what I want now is to be able to use the content of those variables when setting wich profile to use with :

```
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- Filter name -->
            <cogepat.filter.properties>dev.properties</cogepat.filter.properties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

But my variables are not being filled, when using :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-ant-rename-war</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                 <copy file="mavencopyfrom/adeplacer.txt" tofile="mavencopyto/${prefix}_${fileOneName}${machineName}.txt"/>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What I end up with is a file named :

```
${prefix}_${fileOneName}${machineName}.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the properties like this instead:

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <machineName>marin</machineName>
        <prefix>DEV</prefix>
        <fileOneName>node</fileOneName>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

That should do the trick.